# How to send Laravel App Logs to AWS CloudWatch

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

My API (Laravel APP) is deployed on AWS Lambda. 
The goal is to log every Request/Response pair to Cloudwatch.

My approach was:
- define Cloudwatch channel inside `config/logging.php` as following:

```
'cloudwatch' => [
            'name' => env('CLOUDWATCH_LOG_NAME', ''),
            'region' => env('CLOUDWATCH_LOG_REGION', ''),
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => env('CLOUDWATCH_LOG_KEY', ''),
                'secret' => env('CLOUDWATCH_LOG_SECRET', '')
            ],
            'stream_name' => env('CLOUDWATCH_LOG_STREAM_NAME', 'laravel_app'),
            'retention' => env('CLOUDWATCH_LOG_RETENTION_DAYS', 14),
            'group_name' => env('CLOUDWATCH_LOG_GROUP_NAME', 'laravel_app'),
            'version' => env('CLOUDWATCH_LOG_VERSION', 'latest'),
            'formatter' => \Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter::class,
            'disabled' => env('DISABLE_CLOUDWATCH_LOG', false),
        ],
```

Than create a API middelware and from there log values to this channel with:

```
Log::channel('cloudwatch')->info('Something happened!');
```

This change is not causing any problems, but I don't see any logs in the AWS CloudWatch.

Any ideas where is the piece that I am missing?

Comment: did you ever sort this out? 